# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException When posting form using jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I am trying to post a form using jQuery $.post method but I am getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException error in Laravel framework. I understand that there is some mismatch in the type of request going to route/controller but I am unable to figure out where.

**jQuery Call**

```
$.post("create", $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    var json=JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json);
    });
```

**Controller**

```
class create extends Controller
{
//
public function createRecord(){

    $test="test";
    return $test;

    }
 }
```

**Routes (web.php)**

```
Route::post('create',array('uses'=>'create@createRecord'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your route like this, if all your doing is passing the controller.

`Route::post('create', 'create@createRecord');`

This is the only thing I can suggest. See if that fixes it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create cors.php in your middleware to allow all requests

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors {

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
}

}
```

In middle ware of verifyCsrfToken.php add this

```
protected $except = [
    //
    'api/*',
];
```

In routes.php create route of your app

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function()
 {     
    Route::post('api/create', 'create@createRecord');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add csrf token to your ajax function. The syntax may not be correct but this is the logic.

```
$.post("create", $("#myForm").serialize(),"_token" : "{{csrf_token()}}", function(data) {
    var json=JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json);
});
```